# Dimensional Analysis

Tags: cipher, visual

My friend drew this diagram to help him remember his password. "It may seem like just a bunch of squares", he said, "but once you put it all together, and read it the right way, you'll see it."

[image: It's not binary]

***What is his password?***

Comment: I've uploaded an XOR of the three pictures [here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-YMUs593BgY8/VUBOnj-kBqI/AAAAAAAAAzk/Zdup-G2sQqk/w342-h134-no/grid.png). Hopefully this will be of some help.

Comment: Is the password very short?

Comment: @Allan The password is very short. Eleven letters, in fact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The password is

> PARADOXICAL

To see why

> As @Allan's already helpfully pointed out in his image
>
>  [image]
>  
>  you can split the entire thing into eleven columns. For each letter, pick the corresponding column from each segment and line them up next to each other, with the top segment first, then the middle, then the bottom. You'll get something like this (minus the gridlines) after you do each column:
>
>  [image]